# Can't run Basic Project Android Studio

Tags: android, emulation, haxm

I would like to know if somebody have ever seen this error :

`Error:Execution failed for task :app:dexDebug`.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Géry\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Géry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Géry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\GÃ©ry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>           at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\GÃ©ry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-3d28343e3df8e6e80a21d0d971136a42b5497cb6.jar (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\GÃ©ry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-77478872aa0535364d5304fdf8af7dec10d775e2.jar (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\GÃ©ry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-5e0e78c43ae2ec0f87bdf71508e11ef120c0e16c.jar (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\GÃ©ry\AndroidStudioProjects\HomeWork1\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-9cd6f31221028cd39cd1b2123b7a150e502efb58.jar (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       5 errors; aborting

When i launch my emulator alone it is working fine, but when I "Run app" i always have this error, and i don't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: exception is saying that you are trying to read file and file is not present on the given path

Comment: Yes, but I verify in the folder and the files exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your project directory to use only basic ASCII characters. The development tools have issues with Unicode characters in the path.